# Subtract a Vlookup value from another cells value only if a cell has a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation, vlookup

I am attempting to automate a spreadsheet and subtract a vlookup value from another cells value only if that cell has a value. Both values are times (hh:mm:ss) where Q3 will always be larger than the vlookup value.

```
=IF(Q3="","",Q3-VLOOKUP('2020 - REVIEW'!B3,'2020 - DETAILED'!B:M,8,FALSE))
```

For some reason the cell returns `#####`, even though Q3 is larger.

Comment: Did you try to enlarge the cell in case the date was too big to show in the current size?

Comment: Given the fact that you are dealing with **times**, make sure the subtraction result is not **negative**.

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP()`'s return will be the decimal version of the value located in the table, but that will not cause any problem with the subtraction.

That leaves two main thoughts for the difficulty:

1. You use "false" for the last argument in `VLOOKUP()` which means that there is an error returned if `VLOOKUP()` fails to find an exact match. This has to be recognized as possible due to a variety of reasons, so you must take it into account even if this had not happened. If the error is returned, an error will be returned by the full formula, unless Q3 is empty, of course. If the error is too wide to display in the column, you will get the "####" display.
2. The looked up value is always smaller than the value in Q3. Well, **[insert old saying about nickels and every time I heard a thing and then it didn't work out that way]**. Then you will have a negative result and get the "####" display.

You basically need to see what is really there and there are a variety of ways to do so. One is using the Evaluate Formula feature and its a good one,especially for a short formula like this. Another is to simply widen the column. If the display is suddenly something different, you can figure the problem from it. Interestingly, you can distinguish immediately (doing this) between the two ideas just above:  if it is the error, widening a modest amount ought to show it plainly. If it is a negative value (so I get another nickel), you will just go from "####" to "##########" and so on.

But the surest way is to simply bring up the cell formatting function (`Ctrl-1` or with the mouse) and change the format to General while watching the way Excel shows you it will display the contents. If you have the error, yo uwill see exactly that right off. If it is a negative value, you will see that right off as well.

Then proceed as needed.

I find it hard to imagine that dealing with formatted times (hh:mm:ss) and hoping for a result formatted similarly, that you did not have a wide enough column to display the `#N/A` error. So I;m pretty sure the lookup is bringing back a value that is larger than Q3.

The part about it always being larger does not have to be false, in a normal way, by the way. It could be entered badly, or brought from somewhere where it was entered badly. It could, for instance, be a date and time, not just a time. Format it as time, and it will happily show just the time element. But it will also have an integer portion (time is completley the decimal portion of a date-time value) and if Q3 is truly a time only, then the value being stored would be wildly negative while the time portion of it truly is smaller than Q3, always. So false and true when not looked at equally.

One can solve the problem you find. For instance, if the lookup returns an error, just wrap the lookup, or better, the formula, in `IFERROR()` (or test only for the #N/A error so toher errors still force your notice) so that you get back a result that shows you the problem. If the lookup is returning a date-time, not just a time, you can strip the result of the integer portion and continue on. All solvable, once you know what is going wrong. Also, anything else that could cause a problem, perhaps spelling the sheet names if you didn't click to make that lookup table range, can be evaluated. Sometimes numbers imported, especially from websites, will not really be numbers to Excel as they will contain problems, some not addressable by us, so Excel will fail the lookup for that subtle reason. Hard to notice, but easy to solve. Search this site for ways to fix it, but if you got it from a website, look for one that extracts numerical characters, not one that offers to clean up, or `CLEAN()`, your data.

I think it's almost certain though that the lookup table has values that are date-times, like 43056.2384775, not simply times like 0.2384775, or values that have website trash in them. It'd be a likely bet ayway, but mostly I figure your column is already too wide to be showing an error since the error is a short one to display.

(I don't mean to demean website programmers. I do realize their purpose is to display information so it is useful to the website, not preserve the ability to easily steal, um, import, it from the displayed page. There is no fault in that.)